# how to remove "," from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

original string is `"a,d,k"`
I want to remove all `,` and make it to `"adk"`.

I tried code below but it doesn't work.

```
"a,d,k".replace(/,/,"")
```

Comment: "Doesn't work"? Please elaborate. What "doesn't work" about it?

Comment: I searched for the same questions. thnaks for saving my time

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You aren't assigning the result of the replace method back to your variable. When you call replace, it returns a new string without modifying the old one.

For example, load this into your favorite browser:

```
<html><head></head><body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var str1 = "a,d,k";
        str1.replace(/\,/g,"");
        var str2 = str1.replace(/\,/g,"");
        alert (str1);
        alert (str2);
    </script>
</body></html>
```

In this case, `str1` will still be `"a,d,k"` and `str2` will be `"adk"`.

If you want to change `str1`, you should be doing:

```
var str1 = "a,d,k";
str1 = str1.replace (/,/g, "");
```

Comment: +1, but you can just do var str2; str2 = str.replace(...). I've expanded on the answer to (hopefully) improve it.

Comment: If you want to do it without a regex `str.split(",").join("")`

Answer (score 42):

Use [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), e.g.

```
var str = "a,d,k";
str = str.replace( /,/g, "" );
```

Note the `g` (global) flag on the regular expression, which matches all instances of ",".

Answer (score 7):

If U want to delete more than one characters, say comma and dots you can write

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mystring = "It,is,a,test.string,of.mine" 
  mystring = mystring.replace(/[,.]/g , ''); 
  alert( mystring);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like:

```
var str = "a,d,k";
str.replace(/,/g, "");
```

Answer (score -2):

`<script type="text/javascript">var s = '/Controller/Action#11112';if(typeof s == 'string' && /\?*/.test(s)){s = s.replace(/\#.*/gi,'');}document.write(s);</script>`

It's more common answer. And can be use with `s= document.location.href;`

Answer (score -3):

If you need a number greater than 999,999.00 you will have a problem.
These are only good for numbers less than 1 million, 1,000,000.
They only remove 1 or 2 commas.

Here the script that can remove up to 12 commas:

```
function uncomma(x) {
  var string1 = x;
  for (y = 0; y < 12; y++) {
    string1 = string1.replace(/\,/g, '');
  }
  return string1;
}
```

Modify that for loop if you need bigger numbers.

Comment: The `g` in your regex means global and will remove all the commas from the string on the first pass the other 11 loops do nothing. Also you don't need to escape the comma character in the literal. I would advise not being so hostile and critical of other people's answers.

Comment: Strange that it works for me with 11 loops, and not with 1 pass.

Comment: Also I was not being "hostile" or "critical".  Just informing that the above example is flawed and does not work for numbers greater that 1 million.  I needed the code, tested it, it failed, and I have posted my solution which worked only with 11 loops, did not work with 1.  Can you tell me why that is?  It goes against what you are saying.  So I am unsure.