# Trim Function Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that returns values from a database.
My issue: the function adds "" on the return values. I need to trim the values before displaying them on the user's screen.

This is my function

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function handleProcedureChange(procedureid)
    {
        procedureid= document.form1.procedure.value;
        //alert(procedureid);
        var url ="some URL goes here"; 
        url=url+"ProcedureID="+procedureid;

        $.get(url, function(procedureResult) {
            $("#procedureDescription").text(procedureResult);
        });
    }
   </script>
```

The `prcedureResult` is the value being returned and the one I need to trim from the quotes before displaying it.

Comment: Fix the problem at the root - dont mess around removing the quotes in JavaScript

Comment: I don't see you useing any trim function, so what problem are you having with it?

Comment: @ManseUK You are right my friend. I will edit my question and add more tags.Thanks

Comment: @FelixKling I need to use a trim function

Comment: @ManseUK your version works with the fix by Rocket. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything or searched at least? There are many related questions, like [How do I trim a string in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript), [Javascript: How to remove characters from end of string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597611/javascript-how-to-remove-characters-from-end-of-string), [how to remove “,” from a string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908608/how-to-remove-from-a-string-in-javascript),...

Comment: @FelixKling I did on other forums but not here. Thanks for the links. They will come handy in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to remove quotes :

```
$.get(url, function(procedureResult) {
     procedureResult = procedureResult.replace(/^"+|"+$/g, "");
     $("#procedureDescription").text(procedureResult);
});
```

This replaces `"` from the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string with nothing (`""`)

Comment: What's `replaceAll`?  Shouldn't that be `procedureResult.replace(/^"|"$/g, "");`?

Comment: A string in javascript doesn't have a `replaceAll` method

Comment: @JaredPar ta .. must have been day-dreaming !

Comment: I don't believe the updated version will work either.  You're specifying a regex as a string literal and hence it won't be interpreted as a regex.

Comment: @ManseUK: It's still not right.  It needs it be a regex, you can use the regex literal: `.replace(/^"+|"+$/g, "")` (note the `+`, so it matches all `"`).

Comment: @Crematorio: You're welcome, but give this answer the credit, I just helped fix it up :-P

Answer (score 3):

Try the following function which will strip off all leading and trailing quotes from a string value

```
function stripQuotes(str) {
  str = str.replace(/^\"*/, '');
  str = str.replace(/\"*$/, '');
  return str;
}
```

It can be used as so

```
$.get(url, function(procedureResult) {
  procedureResult = stripQuotes(procedureResult);
  $("#procedureDescription").text(procedureResult);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the code on the previews answer and it worked fine.